# Program that displays your born time

Tags: c#

```
            Console.WriteLine("What year where you born?");
            int const born_year = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("You were born in this year " + born_year);
            Console.ReadLine();
```

When I try to add a const to the variable int I get the following errors:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqLNv.png)

Comment: omit the `const`-keyword

Comment: this isn't javascript https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Comment: `const` is `const`, you cannot change it, even from your keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the way you define a constant is `const type var_name = <literal>`

Here is an example:

```cs
const int zero = 0;
```

Second of all, you can only assign literals and other compile-time values. So only "hand-written" numbers, characters and strings like `1`, `2`, `3`, `'a'`, `'b'`, `"abc"` and so on. So you should omit the `const` keyword:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("What year where you born?");
int born_year = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("You were born in this year " + born_year);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

A `const` is a *compile-time* constant. However `Console.ReadLine()` surely just returns a value at *runtime*. So this cannot be done. Delete the `const`-keyword:

```
Console.WriteLine("What year where you born?");
int born_year = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("You were born in this year " + born_year);
Console.ReadLine();
```

If you wanted something that can be assigned exactly *once* similar to JAVAs `final`, you'd need to create a [`readonly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/readonly) field in your class that you assign from within a constructor.

Comment: The confusion comes from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Comment: @Jodrell which however seems pretty similar to the JAVA `final` from what I know.